# Solid tutorial for building a simple wiki application in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wiki, clone

I've searched and I've found a lot that are antiquated.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily create a wiki with [zena](http://zenadmin.org) (a rails CMS):

1. You create an empty application with
   `zena wiki`
2. You initialize an empty database
   `cd wiki; rake zena:init RAILS_ENV=production`
3. You set the publish, write and read groups of a node to "public" (use the wrench tool, "drive" tab)
4. You change the anonymous user's status from "moderated" to "user" (user management by clicking on the "Admin User" link)

And you have a wiki with multilingual support (if you need it) and the usual versioning, diff tools and image management.

Answer (score 2):

I think building an application like that from scratch would be much easier trust me! The reason why I dont suggest building from CMS or any other gem is because you need to learn how it works which might be easier but integrating it into your application is tough and it gets tougher especially when the versions are different. I built wiki for one of the social networking website that I was building. It is simple. I built it just like I built a blog. Each blog has a post and an Author just like wiki has a user and a question asked by the user.

Blog has comments and wiki has answer to the question. Every other minor details follow along. I am still in the process of building a robust wiki with these basics. So I will be happy to help with any more questions that follow along.

The video that helped me with this process is:

```
http://media.rubyonrails.org/video/rails_blog_2.mov
```

Feel free to ask any more doubts that follow. I will be happy to share the code that I built.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you want to take a look at the instiki sourcecode: http://github.com/parasew/instiki - there is lots of code you can reuse. have fun!

Answer (score 0):

You looked at these?  http://www.digitalmediaminute.com/article/1816/top-ruby-on-rails-tutorials

None of them are "solid"?

Comment: I don't think that he's arguing against finding *any* solid rails tutorials.  I think the issue is finding solid *building a wiki on rails* tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe looking at working examples might help you as well. I do not know wiki tutorial for rails, but know about these wiki solutions, written on the top of rails and without rails, but written in ruby:

- [irwi](http://github.com/alno/irwi) is a complete wiki plugin for Ruby on Rails
- [instiki](http://www.instiki.org/show/HomePage) - another wiki running on rails
- [riki wiki](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?RikiWiki) - this is fun: it was written in ruby for the shortest wiki contest, it is not documented, but the code might explain itself