# Wiki software that runs wiki.rubyonrails.org available for download?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is the wiki software that runs http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/ available for download? I can't find it anywhere, thank you :)

I've been investigating rails wikis, tried Instiki but still needs much work, other rails wiki suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the meta generator tag in the source of any page on http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/ it appears to be [DokuWiki](http://www.dokuwiki.org/dokuwiki)

Comment: Teach me for not looking, I just assumed it would be in ruby! :)

Comment: Have a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059949/solid-tutorial-for-building-a-simple-wiki-application-in-ruby-on-rails/2081788#2081788 for a wiki based on zena (a rails CMS).